# How do I write a Schema that suppresses elements with a particular attribute value?

Tags: java, schema, jaxb

I am relatively new to JAXB, but I have a question that seems to be difficult to resolve via online documentation.  My goal is simple: I have XML that is being parsed using JAXB, such that elements where `included=false` should not be part of the resulting object model.

I would like to solve this within the schema:

```
<complexType name="baseFilterType">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="string">
            <attribute type="string" name="code" use="required"/>
            <attribute type="boolean" name="isMandatory" default="false"/>
            <attribute type="boolean" name="included" default="true"/>
        </extension>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="baseFiltersType">
    <sequence>
        <element type="rptt:baseFilterType" name="filter" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
          minOccurs="0" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

So, **how do I change the schema shown above such that the any `baseFilterType` where `included = false` will not be apart of the object model generated for a `baseFiltersType` object**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage the @XmlPath extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), I'm the MOXy tech lead.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseFiltersType {

    private List<BaseFilterType> filter;

    @XmlPath("filter[@included='true']")
    public List<BaseFilterType> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(List<BaseFilterType> baseFilterType) {
        this.filter = baseFilterType;
    }

}
```

**Answer to Related Question**

In one of my answers to a related question I demonstrate how to use MOXy's @XmlPath annotation, and a StAX StreamFilter approach that would work with any JAXB implementation:

- [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542)

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: @Ryan Delucchi - In an answer to a  related question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542 ), I have added an example of using a StAX StreamFilter.  This would mean you would not need to make any Schema or JAXB changes to get the behvaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!  I think I like the StreamFilter approach best.  Simplicity is what I am after for this particular task.  Cheers.