# Is there a way to map the value of a node when the node also has inner nodes?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm currently using JAXB annotations, which work great for most cases.  However, I've come across something I can't figure out how to process/create annotations for.  I have the following XML:

```
   <animals>
      <animal>
        cat
        <age>5</age>
        <color>red</color>
      </animal>
   </animals>
```

Is there a way I can just get "`cat`" out of that XML without fetching "`5`" or "`red`"?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "animals")
public class Animal {

    @XmlElement(name = "animal")
    String type;
}
```

But when I unmarshall this I just get an empty string.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is a full working example of what I'm trying to do:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "animals")
private static class Animals {

    @XmlElement(name = "animals")
    String animalType;
}


    // This code is in "main"
    final String animalsXml = "<animals><animal>cat<color>red</color><age>5</age></animal></animals>";

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animals.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(animalsXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    Animals animals = (Animals)um.unmarshal(bais);

    boolean animalIsCat = animals.animalType == null ? false : animals.animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("cat");
    assert animalIsCat;
    // end code in main
```

Comment: can you share how you do the unmarshalling please?

Comment: mkro, I added the full code I'm using.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "animals")
public class Animals {

    @XmlElement(name = "animal")
    List<Animal> animals;
}

public class Animal {

    @XmlMixed
    List<Object> content;
}
```

Now, the `content` field of `Animal` will contain a mix of `String` and `JAXBElement` objects. You'll need to examine them at runtime to extract the bits you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the xml structure should be coherent - put the type of the animal into the "type" tag:

```
<animals>
    <animal>
        <type>cat</type>
        <age>5</age>
        <color>red</color>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <type>dog</type>
        <age>7</age>
        <color>orange</color>
    </animal>
</animals>
```

Then you have two options.
1. Building on your example, you need two classes: one for animals and one for animal, because by default JAXB maps every tag to a class. While you need a collection for "containing" the objects in java, xml doesn't and that's where the difference comes from. The corresponding annotations:

```
package sample;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="animals")
public class Animals
{
    @XmlElement(name="animal")
    public List<Animal> animals;

    public static class Animal
    {
        public String type;
        public String color;
        public Integer age;
    }

}
```

However, this solution is not the most elegant. If you simply want to skip the container class from the middle, you can use the @XmlElementWrapper annotation:

```
package sample;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="MyDocument")
public class MyDocument
{
    public String comment;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="animals")
    @XmlElement(name="animal")
    public List<Animal> animals;


    public static class Animal
    {
        public String type;
        public String color;
        public Integer age;
    }


}
```

The xml would be like that:

```
<MyDocument>
    <animals>
        <animal>
            <type>cat</type>
            <age>5</age>
            <color>red</color>
        </animal>
        <animal>
            <type>dog</type>
            <age>7</age>
            <color>orange</color>
        </animal>
    </animals>
</MyDocument>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that the XML structure should be coherent, and the XML structure this XML belongs to is driving me nuts.  However, I can't control the structure of the XML, so I have to make due.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JAXB to unmarshal a StAX input and leverage a StreamFilter to eliminate the unwanted nodes:

- [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542)