# How to ignore (efficiently) most part of an XML structure when unmarshalling with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

When processing a web service response with a quite complex XML structure, I am only interested with a very small subset of information. Lets consider the using JAXB has to be used in this context.

As an example, lets say I am only interested in retrieving d (which can be modeled as a single JAXB bean):

```
a
  b1
    c1
    c2
  b2
    d
```

What is the fastest recommended way to ignore everything else but retrieve d?

Comment: I'm guessing that you can't use xpath, that you have to use jaxb, correct?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this question. actually, I am also trying to do something similar but for some reason, it's not working as expected. I tried the things mentioned in this answer as well. I tried this approach and the example from the authors blog but still the JAXB Marshalling does not work as expected with `@XmlPath`. Seems like the XML produced with and without `@XmlPath` are the same. Can you please once look into this example and provide your answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500565/xmlpath-has-no-impact-during-the-jaxb-marshalling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([**JSR-222**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

There are a couple of different ways that you could handle this use case:

**Option #1 - `StreamFilter` Any JAXB Implementation**

You could use a StAX `XMLStreamReader` with a `StreamFilter` to filter out the portions of the XML document that you don't wish to map to:

- [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542)

**Option #2 - `@XmlPath` in MOXy JAXB**

You could use the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlPath("b2/d/text()")
    private String d;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the fastest way would depend on exactly how the xml is formatted. E.g. you could create your own `InputStream` that wraps the real `InputStream` and just be on the lookout for `"<d>"` to trigger you to start passing data through to jaxb.

e.g.

```
   InputStream is = // get real stream
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   Object o = u.unmarshal( new MySpecialStream(is) );
```

If you needed a more xml-like approach then you could create your own [`XMLStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) that only passed on certain calls if you were inside a `d` element.

e.g.

```
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   XMLStreamReader xsr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader( ... );
   Object o = u.unmarshal( new MyXSRWrapper(xsr) );
```

Comment: Your StAX approach can be implemented using a `StreamFilter` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492128/how-to-ignore-efficiently-most-part-of-an-xml-structure-when-unmarshalling-with/7493327#7493327

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to select the desired element as a DOM node and unmarshal using that selected node.

Comment: Sometimes it's a massive waste of time and space creating a DOM tree just for this.

Comment: @biziclop So is premature optimization. What does 'fastest' refer to, development time or processing time, and what is more expensive?

Comment: I don't know, but as I pointed out, DOM is often simply not an option.