# JAXB unmarshall and embedded XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML who embed the XSD, so it's something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="elem2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="elem3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="elem4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="elem5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table>
    <elem1>random1</elem1>
    <elem2/>
    <elem3>random3</elem3>
    <elem4>random4</elem4>
    <elem5>random5</elem5>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm currently using the a clone of the embedded XSD as Schema :

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Table">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="elem2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="elem3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="elem4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="elem5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But the problem is that, when i want to unmarshal an entry XML I get the following error message :

> unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", local:"schema"). Expected elements are <{}Table>

I tried to add the  tag on my XSD but without success, still get an error because of the namespace (i guess ?).
Any help and explanations would be really appreciate.

Comment: Are you trying to map the schema fragment or ignore it?  Do you want it included in the XML output when you do a marshal operation?

Comment: If I can skip the schema fragment inside the XMLs, it would be perfect ! I don't use it for the output XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage a StAX `StreamFilter` on an `XMLStreamReader` so that the elements corresponding to the XML schema are not reported as events. Then you can unmarshal from the `XMLStreamReader` with JAXB.

- [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542)

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I could avoid to remove it via StAX. Will do it like you suggest !