# Filtering out elements based on sub elements with XMLStreamReader and StreamFilter

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I want to do something similar to XMLStreamReader example @BlaiseDoughan gave in his response to [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542) however I need to make the filtering decision based on sub elements not current node attributes.

XMLStreamReader does not have a peek API like XMLEventReader. For example, I want to unmarshall the following XML into a Gump object whose records list ends up only containing 1 item, the record whose associated name does not start with "Filtered-".

I'm using Eclipselink 2.3.2v20111124-r10461

```
<gump>
    <foo>Some text</foo>
    <bar>1.245</bar>
    <records>
        <record>
            <name>Filtered-Counter</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </record>
        <record>
            <name>Golden</name>
            <value>shiny</value>
        </record>
    </records>
    <baz>1234</baz>
</gump>
```

**Gump.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "gump")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Gump implements Serializable {

    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private String baz;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "record")
    private List<Record> records;

    // .. Field getters/setters 

    public Gump() {
      records = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to do a regular unmarshal, and then use an unmarshal listener that cleans up the collection on the after unmarshal event.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback

Comment: Thnx for your feedback. So with this approach you are suggesting the listener is attached to the unmarshalling of Gump and it would I presume need to iterate and remove elements meeting the filtering criteria. If so that approach feels like it would be less performant then a solution that discards/filters them out them as they are encountered in the stream processing during unmarshalling. Is that the case or am I missing something?

Comment: @NBW - StAX is a top down parser so you are not going to be able to exclude a parent based on its children since you don't have access to the children.  Performance them comes down to which is faster:   `Unmarshalling and then throwing away` vs `A process of storing up XML events looking at them and then applying them`.

Comment: This approach worked well. Too bad you can't tell the reader to throw out the current node because in this cause I could have a callback on Record tell the reader to essentially not add itself to the DOM thats being constructed.